# GA recorded SKU ID as transaction ID and show 0 quantity

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm experiencing an unusual occurrence in the GA Conversion Report. Specifically, I am following the instructions provided in the Google Developer Guide for Data Layer Set Up (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ua/gtm/enhanced-ecommerce) for the order confirmation page.

In the GA Report, I have observed that certain orders are displayed twice, however, they are not true duplicates (as evidenced by the attached image [GA Conversion report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDJAy.png)). Instead, the report displays the SKU ID as the transaction ID, but with a quantity of 0. This phenomenon appears to be limited to a subset of orders.

I cant find any patterns behind the duplicate orders. Thought it is the problem with the data layer setup but I follow exactly Google Guide.

Have anyone ever seen this? And how can I fix it.

Thanks a million!

[Purchase Event Data Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeAys.png)

Comment: Show your dataLayer of Purchase, pls.

Comment: @MichelePisani Here is the data layer on the Purchase Event

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeAys.png  @MichelePisani